# Map whose keys are compared using eq

Tags: scala, collections, equality

Is anyone aware of a `Map` implementation for Scala which does *not* use equality (`==`) but object identity (`eq`) for key comparisons. That is, if I have

```
case class Foo()
val a = Foo()
val b = Foo()
```

Then I want

```
 EqMap(a -> 1, a -> 2).toVector == Vector(a -> 2)
```

and

```
 EqMap(a -> 1, b -> 2).toVector == Vector(a -> 1, b -> 2)
```

?

I know I can wrap my keys like this:

```
class Eq[A <: AnyRef](val peer: A) {
  override def hashCode = peer.hashCode
  override def equals(that: Any) = that match {
    case e: Eq[_] => peer eq e.peer
    case _ => false
  }
}

case class Foo()

val a = Foo()
val b = Foo()

a == a // true
a == b // true
new Eq(a) == new Eq(a) // true
new Eq(a) == new Eq(b) // false
```

But I would prefer not to pay the overhead of wrapping everything.

Comment: so `java.util.IdentityHashMap` will do the job, luckily in my case I can use a mutable map.

Comment: So you're stuck on 2.10 or 2.11 and you're unable to downgrade?  That's too bad.  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/collection/jcl/IdentityHashMap.html